# Oracle SQL: Transpose Columns to Rows After Using Extract

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with column DATE. Date is 'dd/mm/yyyy' and I want only days. So I try with extract and return what I need, but I what using transpose for column to row.
The select statement is:

```
select EXTRACT (DAY FROM "DATE") DAY
from people;
```

Is this thing possible?

Thank you!

Comment: would be helpful if you could provide sample data and expected result ?

Comment: seems you want unpivoting, but how many columns, and which restriction within the WHERE condition do you have? Here, there is only one column...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string, then just use the leftmost two characters:

```
select substr("DATE", 1, 2) as day
```

That said, you should not be storing dates as strings.  It is wrong, wrong, wrong.   You cannot use the built-in date/time functions.  You cannot use inequality comparisons either.  Fix your data model.

Comment: Dates it's date, not a string.

Comment: @louisssee but you said *Date is 'dd/mm/yyyy'*. A date has no format, so it looked like you were talking about a string.

Answer (score 0):

The date format doesn't matter. It is linked to your NLS local settings and this is how you see this.

To have it generic and extract DAY from the date do this:
`select to_char(sysdate, 'DD') from dual;`

Would return `07` since it's September 7th 2020.